# "In/on the App Store"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, trademarks

This is the official Apple logo for apps:

[image: Available on the App Store!]

What's the logic behind using *on* instead of *in*? It doesn't sound grammatically correct.

Comment: Can't you just imagine Apple spending weeks agonizing over this choice of words, with Jobs using the word "shit" a lot? Like "Think different"?

Comment: They had to pick one. Neither is meaningful, so it didn't matter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Apple App store is not a physical store but an online one, so we use *on* in the same way we say *on the internet*.

Comment: Or *on Facebook.*

Comment: Ok, it would make sense if it was web page, but it's mostly used as a phone app. And you have stuff *in* app, not *on* app.

Comment: That may be true of stuff that you keep *in* the app, but in the circumstance before us you are using the app to access stuff *on* the Apple store site.

Comment: Yep. It applies to anything related to the Internet, like, on the website, on the network, on the Twitter post, etc...

Comment: The same usage occurs with *"I got it on eBay"*. To me it suggests that such places are bigger, yet more accessible, than if the preposition were "in" or "at" (where you might have to look around to find something, or go to some trouble to get there in the first place).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *"on eBay"*, makes sense, because because *"on auction"* and *"on the market"*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this question is not about English grammar or usage, but about commercial product presentation and audience psychology.

The accepted answer suggests that the use of ‘on’ reflects established usage in a particular context, but I find the comparison with reference to general media (**on** the Internet) rather strained. I find ‘**in**’ more natural in these circumstances:

> You can by this **in** Walmart

> You can by this **in** the store

So I think it justified to consider the psychology behind what I believe is Apple’s deliberate use of **on**?

One possibility was to avoid the implication that one had to get up off the couch and drive to a physical location, and go **into** a physical store to purchase this “magical experience”.

A second, mundane, possibility is that Apple did not wish confusion with its bricks-and-mortar stores: you might try or buy a device **in** the Apple Store, but not **on** it. Using ‘**on**’ with the App Store when it was first launched, emphasized that it was something different.

Consistent with this suggested concern for distinguishing the App Store from the Apple Store, the [official badge](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/) has now been changed, replacing “Available” by ”Download”:

[image: App Store badge 2020]

(And the choice of **on** was not *so* outlandish, in the sense that a shop assistant might say ”You can find it over there, sir, **on** the shelf by the…”.)